# How to compile a cpp file with the alglib library?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, alglib

I'm working on a C++ code on linux that needs some special functions which can be provided by alglib: https://www.alglib.net/download.php. The thing is, i'm new to Ubuntu so I don't know how to install the library or execute the files I need for my program.

The library's manual (https://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#gs_attaching) explain that you should just pick the packages you need and add them to your project, so I downloaded the tgz file and added specialfunctions.h, and executed it like this:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<specialfunctions.h>
```

But when I run the compiler through terminal I get this error:

**analitica.cpp:3:9: fatal error: specialfunctions.h: No such file or directory
3 | #include<specialfunctions.h>
|         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.**

Someone has a hint of what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `sudo apt install libalglib-dev` would seem like the easiest option?

Comment: Looks like you're probably not specifying the path to the library's include folder. Usually that's done by adding `-I<path to include folder>` to the compiler command line.

Comment: @AlanBirtles installed it, but the same thing happened

Comment: @user4581301 I ran gcc -I/laura/Documents/IC/analytic/include  -o analitica analitica.cpp and I got the same error

Comment: `/laura/Documents/IC/analytic/include` is an unusual path for a Debian-based system. Give `/home/laura/Documents/IC/analytic/include` a try.